# Simple const in javascript is not working in my function

Tags: javascript

I try to simplify my code with a const but it isn't working

```
// my const 'myscroll' is not working ?? Why ??

const myscroll = document.querySelector('.scrollup');

// When the user scrolls down 20px from the top of the document, show the button
window.onscroll = function () {scrollFunction()};

function scrollFunction() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 800 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 800) {
    myscroll.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    myscroll.style.display = "none";
  }
};
```

I have to do it that way

```
window.onscroll = function () {scrollFunction()};

function scrollFunction() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 800 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 800) {
    document.querySelector('.scrollup').style.display = "block";
  } else {
    document.querySelector('.scrollup').style.display = "none";
  }
};
```

It must be so simple but I'm blind !
Thanks for your helps

Comment: Put the `const myscroll = …;` inside the `scrollFunction` so that it doesn't run before the document is loaded - like your original did.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "not working"? What are you trying to do?

Comment: please check whether **myscroll**  has some values in it i think it would be null. and if it is null your js is loading before the html content is rendered.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const myscroll = document.querySelector('.scrollup');

window.onscroll = scrollFunction;

function scrollFunction(e) {
    const state = document.documentElement.scrollTop > 200;
    myscroll.style.display = state ? 'block' : 'none';
};
```

```css
body {
    height: 500vh;
}

.scrollup {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="scrollup"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks @MoloF
The style is a way much better.
But I still have the same issue.

I have to do this to make it works in localhost :

`
const state = document.documentElement.scrollTop > 400;
  document.querySelector('.scrollup').style.display = state ? 'block' : 'none';
`

Comment: @Lo1176, 
I understand correctly, you have a problem on the `local machine`? Perhaps you write the `JS` code first and then the `html`? Try adding `JS` to the very bottom inside the `BODY` tag